# Displaying grep content on a new line

Tags: php, grep

I have got a grep file that I use to search files for certain pieces of text.

However, when the results are displayed they all appear in one chunk and are a little jumbled.

Is there a way that the text can be displayed on a new line or paragraph, or a more uniform manner?

```
 <?php
  $command = "grep -ri 'manchester' ./*";
  $output = shell_exec($command);
  echo "$output";
  echo "Grep job over.";
  ?>
```

Comment: What is a "more uniform manner" for you? Can you show how it should look like and what you tried to format the output?

Comment: Are running this script from the command line or visiting it in your browser?

Comment: Visited within a browser. A more uniformed manner would be 1 result per line

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you are visiting it in your browser and this is the entire script you should take into account that by default (without sending any headers) the output will be interpreted as HTML by your browser.

The result of your grep command uses the new line character (\n) to separate its contents, but in HTML a new line is not generated by a character, the 
 tag can be used, for example.

So you can try to replace

```
echo "$output";
```

with

```
echo nl2br($output");
```